# Deformed "ellipsis" python

Tags: python-3.x

How to draw two deformed "ellipses" with different shapes and the same volume? I mean the shape like in the picture.

[image]

Comment: Do you have an analytical expression for the shape you want?

Comment: No, I look for it without any success

Comment: How is that a deformed ellipse? Its just a free form shape. You could equally say its a deformed triangle.

Comment: Yes, it may be deformed triangle, I need some general shape and next different general shape with the same area

Comment: What about bumpy? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51259361/smooth-a-bumpy-circle/51267877 is it possible to compute area of it?