# How to fit a ellipse to given points in Octave

Tags: graphics, octave, least-squares, ellipse, approximation

I would like to know how to fit a bunch of (x,y) points in an ellipse shape. I've got two vectors, both the same size [1001,1], but I don't know how to fit an ellipse. Every time I tried the least squares it ends in some different approximation. I was using trigonometric polynomials by the way.

Here is an image of the graphic plot.

I will appreciate any help :)

**Image plot**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4vnt.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Covariance Matrix of an Ellipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146383/covariance-matrix-of-an-ellipse)

Comment: More of the same here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51267877/7328782 — Hope that solves your problem!