# Fit 2D ellipse based on sparse set of edge coordinates (MATLAB, Python)

Tags: python, matlab, math

I want to fit an ellipse based on a sparse set of edge coordinates. All functions I find online for explicit edge coordinate are based when 2 opposite coordinates of the edge and an additional tangent edge coordinate are known. I would argue that any ellipse can be fitted when at least 3 edge coordinates are known. For my application I have a sparse set of coordinates (but greater then 3) which are also all occurring on only a small section of the total ellipse.

I cant image that there is no standardized function to tackle this problem. Yet, I was not able to find it.

Best would be if the solution works in MATLAB but python would also be welcome.

Thanks in advance!

matplotlib.patches.Ellipse

fitellipse.m https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15125-fitellipse-m

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/87584-object-oriented-tools-for-fitting-conics-and-quadrics

Comment: Any _circle_ can be uniquely fit to three points. An ellipse needs one more (you can fit an infinite number of ellipses through three points). And if you have _more_ than four points, the odds of you being able to fit an ellipse are basically zero thanks to finite precision number formats. So: search the web for "fit ellipse to 4 points" and you should find quite a few results.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. Seems about right that infinite number of ellipses fit trough 3 points. Luckily, I have up 8 - 10 points

Comment: The least-squares solution proposed by Wolfie below is good if you expect normal noise on your coordinates. If you expect to have outlier coordinates, then a RANSAC approach might be better.

Comment: Even if you _have_ 8-10 points, you don't _want_ 8-10 points. Select 4 from your "more than 4" set, and ignore the rest. Or to boost confidence in the ellipse found, simply build two or more ellipses by picking multiple sets of 4 and seeing if they generate (approximately, up to some error value) the same ellipse.

Comment: If the points are distributed all around the ellipse, you can fit an ellipse by computing the covariance matrix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47539536/7328782

Answer (score 1):

The formula for an ellipse is

```
ax^2 + by^2 = r^2 = 1;
```

This assumes the radius `r=1` without loss of generality, since we can simply scale `a` and `b` by `1/r` if we start out with any other radius.

Then we can turn this into a matrix equation for some array of `n` points on the ellipse:

```
[x0, y0].^2 * [a; b] = [1, 1, 1, ...]
```

Where `x0` and `y0` are column vectors, `a` and `b` are scalars, and the result is an array of ones with the same number of elements as `x0` or `y0`.

This is a problem of the form `Ax = B`, which is a candidate for solving **in a least-squares sense** using [`mldivide` or `\`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html).

*Note that there's not a unique solution to fit an ellipse to only 3 points unless it's a circle.*

We can set up the problem:

```
% Set up an initial ellipse, get 1000 points and plot it
a = 5; 
b = 10;
[x, y] = getEllipsePoints( a, b, 1000 );
```

I've set up the helper function `getEllipsePoints()` to generate `n` points around the ellipse described by `a` and `b`:

```
function [x, y] = getEllipsePoints( a, b, n )
    % Equally spaced points for x, and the corresponding points for y
    x = linspace(-sqrt(1/a), sqrt(1/a), n);
    y = sqrt((1 - (a*x.^2))/b);
    % Top and bottom half of the ellipse
    x = [x,x];
    y = [y,-y];
end
```

Then get a subset of points to do our fit, this sounds like the starting point in your "real" situation:

```
[x0, y0] = getEllipsePoints( a, b, 5 );
```

Formulate them into the `Ax=B` structure required for `mldivide`, noting that `A=[x0,y0].^2` and `B` is an array of ones. To avoid confusion with the x-coordinates I've called the output variable `ab`.

```
A = [x0(:), y0(:)];
B = ones(numel(x0),1);
ab = (A.^2)\B; % ab(1) approximates a, ab(2) approximates b
```

Run a validation check:

```
figure(1); clf; hold on;
plot( x, y, '.', 'markersize', 1, 'displayname', 'full ellipse' );
plot( x0, y0, 'dk', 'markersize', 10, 'displayname', 'points to fit to' );
plot( x2, y2, 'or', 'displayname', 'fitted ellipse' );
axis equal; grid on; legend( 'show' );
```

Output:

[image: plot]

Comment: Your ellipse equation assumes an axis-aligned ellipse. For an arbitrary ellipse there’s one more parameter.

Comment: @CrisLuengo You are right, and for my application it is required to fit an arbitrary ellipse. Would you know how to implement this? For my problem I have 10 coordinates of edge points